# How do you add com.android.nfc_extras.NfcAdapterExtras to Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, nfc

I have found [these](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/com/android/nfc_extras/NfcAdapterExtras.java) classes but how do I add com.android.nfc_extras.NfcAdapterExtras to an eclipse project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not part of the public API, so it is not in the SDK. Download Android source code from AOSP and build the jar yourself. Your other option is to use reflection to access it.

Comment: Thanks,i cant find it,can you get link source code for download com.android.nfc_extras.NfcAdapter Extras?

Comment: Abandon all hope :) Or install Linux in a VM.

Comment: Thanks,however my first problem is I don't know the exact difference between these two solutions.I mean if I use Android source code, then do I have to build and use the application's signature anyway? In this case it seems that using reflection is so easier than dealing with the source code which can be a real headache. I'll appreciate it if you could explain a bit more about these methods, I mean what should I go through each one briefly

Comment: Reflection is generally easier because you don't need to add the classes to your project. You do need to change  `nfcee_access.xml` file in order to get access though. Details and sample code here: http://nelenkov.blogspot.jp/2012/08/accessing-embedded-secure-element-in.html